# How to manage sessions with Laravel 5.0 as backend

Tags: php, android, web-services, laravel, backend

I am developing a web application in Laravel. Now I'm in the process of creating an android app. I need to create a web service (back end) in Laravel, but I don't know how to manage the sessions (`auth`) in the request.

My idea is to create a unique token for every session, and store it in a database. So, every request need the token be included, and my backend will check if the token is valid or not.

How can I modify the login functionality that comes with Laravel 5.0 to create an return the token?

I read the documentation and some articles in the internet, but it is still not clear to me.

Comment: I know you are using L5 but do search for rest-api in laravel, go thru this tutorial to get a picture http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api-updated--net-29785 and search github or packalyst for possible packages that do this for you.

Comment: @Kyslik Seems interesting, and actually works. But i don't know if is a good practice to send username (or email) and password in every request to the API. Am I wrong? If this okay?

Comment: Definitely do search more about the topic, I kind of have in memory that using token is not good (I am not sure!) just search, do not include Laravel 5 in equation for a moment. Search something like "php rest api" etc. get and idea and make it using L5 (middlewares/filters...)

Comment: I always rely on Laracasts.com when I have a question like this - well, when I have any questions at all really! You can get familiar with Laravel 5's authentication in this video: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a filter named `custom_authentication` and check for the token validity inside that filter. Now just apply this filter before every routes, which you want to be authenticated.

Using only simple authentication token is not very secure, you need to go with HTTPS always.

If you want to make the API secure with HTTP, you might have to implement OAuth with the help of packages like [this](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a token during registration of the app which should correspond with the user id. This token will be used together with the user id anytime you call any of your api's to authenticate the user.

Comment: Yeah. I've already did it in Laravel4, but in Laravel 5, i don't know how to extend or edit the registration module. Any hints? or a good tutorial?

Comment: Paste your code so that I can see how I can help coz I have done the same thing and is working fine